# Is it allowed to do subscriptions for unlocked feature version at app store? (not cloud nor web based)

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

my app is like an iPod for web articles. 
You can listen to the web articles. http://lisgo.org/

I am working on a free version with in-app-purchase now.
But, I'm not sure if I can do subscriptions model for a upgraded version on app store.

There is no web version for my app, even though it needs to connect to the internet for 
article parser.

For example,  I want to do like this.
Free version                    = ads, voice speed 1x only, no offline mode.
Premium version (subscriptions) = no ads, multiple voice speeds, offline mode.

I have not seen apps which unlock their features on subscriptions unless it has been 
provided as a web SaaS service.  And, my friend told me it is against apple's guide line,
but I couldn't find the page states that rule.

Any advice will be appreciated so much!

Thanks.

Comment: AFAIK subscription models only apply to magazines - there is no such thing as a legal way to sell app subscriptions for anything but e-magazines.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  But, I see SaaS apps use subscription models on app store to collect their monthly payments very often.  For example, remember the milk, dropbox, evernote, and so on.  I'm wondering if I can use subscription for Premium version of my app which provides editors pick of most interesting stories, premium support, unlocked features like offline mode, multiple voice speed.  In this case, premium version provides some contents and unlocked features at the same time even though it's not connected to web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple said to me that auto-renewable subscriptions are only allowed to publishers, not for web service vendors.

It seemed that I can try non auto-renewable subscriptions because they suggested it, but I haven't tried it yet.  I believe one time in-app-purchase is good for my model for the moment.

The author of Instapaper also talked about this on his podcast, and he needs to use non-renewable subscriptions for his additional subscription model.